# Bootstrap Grid not moving content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out why the bootstrap grid isn't moving my content. I have the library imported, no stray divs, container then row and then col-md-#, but the content never moves. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DirectivesTest">
<head>
    <title>Directives Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div id="header">
            Book Review Site
            </div>
        </div> <!--end row-->
    </div> <!--end container-->
    <div class="container">

        <div ng-controller="BookController">

            <div class="content" ng-repeat="book in books">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-4">
                        {{book.title}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                        {{"Reviews"}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="bookReview in book.review">
                    <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">

                            {{bookReview.body}}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!--End parent ng-repeat-->


        </div>





    </div>
    <book-reviews></book-reviews>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **missing** `bootstrap css` library, include that before your `app.css` every thing well work.

Here is the **cdn** path

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the help